# ‘β’ using Latin Modern fonts

Tags: fonts, greek

I’m typesetting a text with some math and Greek letters. LaTeX handles Greek letters just fine in math mode but I can’t get it to display the character ‘β’ using either direct input or the `\b` macro provided by the `chemmacros` package.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek=textgreek]{chemmacros}

\begin{document}    
\iupac{\b-carotene} % doesn't work

\iupac{β-carotene} % doesn't work

β % doesn't work

\Chembeta % doesn't work

$\beta$ % works fine
\end{document}
```

I’m compiling the document with `lualatex`.

---

## Update

Using a different font (namely, Linux Libertine or Times New Roman) solves the problem. Does that mean the Latin Modern family has no support for upright Greek letters?

Comment: Here, your MWE is fine (`\b`, `\Chembeta` and `$beta$`) except with `β` character (no error and no glyph!).

Comment: `\iupac{\b-carotene}` works for me. May be you should go for update?

Comment: I get three betas like the others with TeX Live 2012. Not sure if I like the italics in β-carotene though. Maybe an upright beta from the Computer Modern Math font would look better?

Comment: It may be that the `aux` file got in the way during testing, since I was playing with many configurations and fonts. I'm indeed looking for the upright beta. I'm updating the question to include the option `[greek=textgreek]` in the `chemmacros` package, which *should* display an upright beta.

Comment: There are evident problems with `textgreek` in LuaLaTeX with `fontspec`, as, for example, `\textbeta` gets redefined.

Comment: Well, `upgreek` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`upgreek` works fine both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Apparently it isn't clear from `chemmacros`' documentation though that setting the option `greek=upgreek` does *not* load `upgreek` and `greek=textgreek` does *not* load `textgreek`! The option exists to prevent `chemmacros` from choosing between `upgreek` or `textgreek` automatically if either of them or both are loaded by the user. Using either option without loading the appropriate package usually throws an error like

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textbeta 

l.9 \iupac{\b-carotene}
```

However, when `fontspec` is loaded, too, the code silently fails with Latin Modern. (I should probably add some checking whether the needed packages are loaded.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{upgreek}% needs no be loaded
\usepackage{chemmacros}[2014/01/24]
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\chembeta}

\begin{document}    
\iupac{\b-carotene} % works

\iupac{β-carotene} % works

β % works

\chembeta % works

$\beta$ % works fine
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A problem is that `\textbeta` gets redefined, so the definition performed by `textgreek` is lost. Moreover, the Latin Modern fonts *don't* support Greek.

Here is a hack, I guess there are better ways to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\protected\def\Chembeta{\text{\fontencoding{LGR}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont b}}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{β}{\Chembeta}

\begin{document}

\iupac{\b-carotene} % works

\iupac{β-carotene} % works

β % works

\Chembeta % works

$\beta$ % works
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complete setting, for the Latin Modern fonts only can be obtained generalizing and streamlining the above hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_protected:Npn \egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n #1
 {
  \mbox{\fontencoding{LGR}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont#1}
 }
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemalpha{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{a}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chembeta{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{b}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemgamma{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{g}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemdelta{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{d}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemepsilon{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{e}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemeta{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{h}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemkappa{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{k}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemmu{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{m}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemnu{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{n}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chempi{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{p}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemrho{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{r}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemsigma{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{s}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \Chemomega{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{w}}
\cs_set_protected:Npn \ChemDelta{\egchemmacros_lgr_greek:n{D}}

\newunicodechar{α}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemalpha}{α}}
\newunicodechar{β}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chembeta}{β}}
\newunicodechar{γ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemgamma}{γ}}
\newunicodechar{δ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemdelta}{δ}}
\newunicodechar{ε}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemepsilon}{ε}}
\newunicodechar{η}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemeta}{η}}
\newunicodechar{κ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemkappa}{κ}}
\newunicodechar{μ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemmu}{μ}}
\newunicodechar{ν}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemnu}{ν}}
\newunicodechar{π}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chempi}{π}}
\newunicodechar{ρ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemrho}{ρ}}
\newunicodechar{σ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemsigma}{σ}}
\newunicodechar{ω}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\Chemomega}{ω}}
\newunicodechar{Δ}{\bool_if:NTF \l_chemmacros_inside_iupac_bool {\ChemDelta}{Δ}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\iupac{\b-carotene} % works

\iupac{β-carotene} % works

β % doesn't work - Latin Modern has no beta

\Chembeta % works

$\beta$ % works fine

\iupac{αβγδεηκμνπρσωΔ} % works

\iupac{\a\b\g\d\k\m\n\w}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fontsetup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsetup) package which provides the functionality to typeset upright Greek for use in chemistry. It uses the New Computer Modern fonts.[image: upright greek chemistry]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    β-carotene

    \(\beta\)-carotene

    \(\upbeta\)-carotene

    \chembeta-carotene

    κ-compound

    \chemkappa-compound
\end{document}
```

Please consult the documentation of the [`newcomputermodern`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern) and the [`fontsetup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsetup?lang=en) packages for further information.