# How to typeset a word containing both Latin and Greek letters?

Tags: greek, chemistry

I want to typeset the word α-aminoacid and the α character is not shown in the compiled pdf file.

I compile using XeTeX and I found only solutions for typesetting greek letters that switch language or writing system, but that's weird to do in mid of a word. I'm also aware of math mode, but this is not math.

Comment: It's not that uncommon to use "math mode" outside of math. For instance, if you want to write $2^{\text{nd}}$ and similar things using sub/superscripts, you use math mode.

Comment: You can see these two links: (chemistry) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76250/%CE%B2-using-latin-modern-fonts?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters?rq=1

Comment: If you use XeTeX one way is `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}`, then just write "α-aminoacid" using UTF8 codes (e.g., Ctrl+Shift+u03b1 type α in some Linux editors) . The font obviously should be one with the greek glyphs (e.g,., do not use the cmr10 for this) .

Comment: Also LuaLaTeX, not just XeTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I used [`textgreek`](https://texblog.org/2012/03/15/greek-letters-in-text-without-changing-to-math-mode/) package and command `\textalpha` to insert α.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues. One of them involves font encoding. Another involves the compiler. Finally, it involves the font (not all of them have the alpha character in the correct Unicode location).

I suggest that you use LuaLaTeX (or XeTeX), which use only utf-8. Then it is a matter of using acceptable fonts. Here is one example:

```
\documentclass{article}
% compile using lualatex, which uses utf-8.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif} % because it has the alpha character.
\begin{document}
% just type or paste from character map
α-aminoacid
\end{document}
```